# How can I gracefully terminate a BLOCKED thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

There are plenty of places that deal with terminating C# threads gracefully. However, they rely on a loop or if condition executing inside a loop, which assumes that this statement will be executed frequently; thus, when the `stop` bool flag is set, the thread exits quickly.

What if I have a thread in which this is not true? In my case, this is a thread set up to receive from a server, which frequently blocks on a call to read data from the input stream, where none is yet provided so it waits.

Here is the thread in question's loop:

```
    while (true)
        {
            if (EndThread || Commands.EndRcvThread)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ending thread.");
                return;
            }

            data = "";
            received = new byte[4096];

            int bytesRead = 0;
            try
            {
                bytesRead = stream.Read(received, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Output.Message(ConsoleColor.DarkRed, "Could not get a response from the server.");
                if (e.GetType() == Type.GetType("System.IO.IOException"))
                {
                    Output.Message(ConsoleColor.DarkRed, "It is likely that the server has shut down.");
                }
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            int endIndex = received.Length - 1;
            while (endIndex >= 0 && received[endIndex] == 0)
            {
                endIndex--;
            }

            byte[] finalMessage = new byte[endIndex + 1];
            Array.Copy(received, 0, finalMessage, 0, endIndex + 1);

            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(finalMessage);

            try
            {
                ProcessMessage(data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Output.Message(ConsoleColor.DarkRed, "Could not process the server's response (" + data + "): " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

The `if` statement at the top of the block does what the usual stopping-a-thread-gracefully setup does: checks a flag, terminates the thread if it's set. However, this thread is usually to be found waiting a few lines further down, at `stream.Read`.

Given this, is there any way to gracefully terminate this thread (i.e. no `Abort`ing), and clean up its resources (there's a client that needs to be closed)?

Comment: Decrease your stream read timeout and retry more frequently, giving you more opportunities to exit.

Comment: @Asad - wasn't aware that was possible. Do I do this with the `TcpClient` I have or the underlying `Socket TcpClient.Client`?

Comment: If this is a `TcpClient`, you can set its `ReceiveTimeout` property to whatever you like. There's probably even a constructor that lets you set it as you make it, although I'm not sure about that.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Your code has a major flaw, You assume you get a full message from `stream.Read` you may only get 1/2 a message during a single read. You really should have some kind of loop in there checking for `'\0'` and if your message has no null charactor it calls read again before it passes `data` off to `ProcessMessage`.

Comment: Use an async Task instead of a thread and supply it with the cancellation token of a `CancelationTokenSource` you create. Pass the cancelation token to `Stream.ReadAsync` and catch the `System.OperationCanceledException` it will throw when `Cancel` is invoked on the token source. Also either check the `IsCanceled` on the token source or call its `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` in your loop.

Comment: @Alex This depends on the OP being in .NET 4.5+, but this is sound advice nonetheless that can be implemented with IAsyncResult et al.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm aware of that possibility; I've specced for it. Since I know the length of all messages between client and server, I know none are longer than 4096 bytes, and if some arrive broken or not complete, they're different enough that I have code that can infer what message it is.

Comment: All great ideas guys, it'd be great if you could post them as answers. Asad,  your idea has worked. Fake internet points await answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can use async / Tasks, the way to do clean stopping of async and IO operations is with a `CancelationToken` that is connected to a `CancelationTokenSource`. The below code snippet illustrates a simplified example of its usage when applied to a simplified version of your code.

```
class MyNetworkThingy 
{
    public async Task ReceiveAndProcessStuffUntilCancelled(Stream stream, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var received = new byte[4096];
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(received, 0, 4096, token);
                if (bytesRead == 0 || !DoMessageProcessing(received, bytesRead))
                    break; // done.
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                break; // operation was canceled.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // report error & decide if you want to give up or retry.
            }
        }
    }

    private bool DoMessageProcessing(byte[] buffer, int nBytes)
    {
        try
        {
            // Your processing code.
            // You could also make this async in case it does any I/O.
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // report error, and decide what to do.
            // return false if the task should not
            // continue.
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        using (var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        using (var myStream = /* create the stream */)
        {
            var receive = new MyNetworkThingy().ReceiveAndProcessStuffUntilCancelled(myStream, cancelSource.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to stop");
            Console.ReadLine();
            cancelSource.Cancel();
            receive.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

.

Comment: Does it work like a thread - as in can I run this and another client simultaneously?

Comment: Tasks are scheduled using thread pool threads. So yes you can have multiple tasks, like you can have multiple threads. The nice thing is that while IO is pending the physical thread pool thread servicing the task will be freed up to do other work, until the IO request completes, is canceled or fails.

Comment: Tasks *can* scheduled using thread pool threads, but they don't have to be. They might run on the same thread (common for async/await in ASP.NET or WPF applications), the thread pool, another thread pool, or their own unique thread (long-running tasks).

Comment: @JonathanAllen true, in this example case however with async IO operations and no instructions like `ConfigureAwait(true)` or creating the task as a long running one, it will likely be several thread pool threads.