# Determine if PipeStream has data

Tags: c#, multithreading, named-pipes

I am using named pipes to communicate some messages between applications.

My pipe client reads a message sent from the server using `PipeStream.ReadByte()`. This blocks the thread it is running in.

This behavior is generally fine, however, I cannot figure out a good way to dispose of that thread while it is being blocked. When the client exits, that thread stays alive until the stream gets some data and it is allowed to check the looping variable again. In the case where the server goes silent, the thread just lives.

`Thread.Abort()` has no effect.

Is there a way to check the stream from data before moving to the `ReadByte()` method? `PipeStream.Length` throws `UnsupportedException`.

Comment: Why not read from the stream asynchronously (`Stream.ReadAsync`) with a cancellation token. When the client exits, call `Cancel` on the associated `CancelationTokenSource` to cancel the pending IO. Also why not use an async task for your IO bound operation instead of a dedicated thread. See e.g. a similar problem / solution for a question I came across yesterday here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29423042/2573395

Comment: Note that it may make sense to optimize the referenced solution for pipes (i.e. to await connection, etc).

Comment: I left an answer a while ago. Would you care to comment on it, or should I delete it because you already found a different solution? If so, could you please post that as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to use async I/O and tasks instead of a dedicated thread, and use a `CancelationToken` to abort pending IO. A simplified example is shown in the code snippet below, which is based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29423042/2573395, but slightly modified for pipe operations (to asynchronously wait for a connection for each message in this case). Note that I am no expert on named pipes, so there may be more optimal ways of doing this.

```
public class MyPipeReader
{
    private string _pipeName;

    public MyPipeReader(string pipeName)
    {
        _pipeName = pipeName;
    }

    public async Task ReceiveAndProcessStuffUntilCancelled(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var received = new byte[4096];
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using (var stream = CreateStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (await WaitForConnection(stream, token))
                    {
                        var bytesRead = 0;
                        do {
                            bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(received, 0, 4096, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        } while (bytesRead > 0 && DoMessageProcessing(received, bytesRead));

                        if (stream.IsConnected)
                            stream.Disconnect();
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    break; // operation was canceled.
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // report error & decide if you want to give up or retry.
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private NamedPipeServerStream CreateStream()
    {
        return new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName, PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
    }

    private async Task<bool> WaitForConnection(NamedPipeServerStream stream, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // We can't simply use 'Task.Factory.FromAsync', as that is not cancelable.
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        var cancelRegistration = token.Register(() => tcs.SetCanceled());
        var iar = stream.BeginWaitForConnection(null, null);
        var rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(iar.AsyncWaitHandle, delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(true); }, null, -1, true);
        try
        {
            await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (iar.IsCompleted) {
                stream.EndWaitForConnection(iar);
                return true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            cancelRegistration.Dispose();
            rwh.Unregister(null);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool DoMessageProcessing(byte[] buffer, int nBytes)
    {
        try
        {
            // Your processing code.
            // You could also make this async in case it does any I/O.
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // report error, and decide what to do.
            // return false if the task should not
            // continue.
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        using (var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var receive = new MyPipeReader("_your_pipe_name_here_").ReceiveAndProcessStuffUntilCancelled(cancelSource.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to stop");
            Console.ReadLine();
            cancelSource.Cancel();
            receive.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note for anyone coming to this thread, you cannot cancel a `ReadAsync` operation with a `CancellationToken`.